# Set a minimum order limit for use of wallet "TeraWallet - For WooCommerce"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

If users try to pay via their wallet, then there should be a minimum order limit. this condition should only be apple only on when the user tries to pay via wallet.

Plugin Name: TeraWallet - For WooCommerce

Plugin URL: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-wallet/

hello everyone, If users try to pay via their wallet, then there should be a minimum order limit. this condition should only be apple only on when the user tries to pay via wallet.

Plugin Name: TeraWallet - For WooCommerce

Plugin URL: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-wallet/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code which I used on one of my sites:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'disable_paypal_below_100' );
 
function disable_paypal_below_100( $available_gateways ) {
    $minimum = 100;
    if ( WC()->cart->total < $minimum ) {
        unset( $available_gateways['paypal'] ); //replace 'paypal' with 'wallet'
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}
```

You can extend it to match your requirements.

**What does this code do?**

This code will check if the order total on checkout is less than 100 then it'll remove PayPal from the payment gateway list.

**UPDATE:**

To enable the WooWallet as a payment gateway again, you can put this code in the **functions.php** file of your child theme.:

```
add_filter('woo_wallet_payment_is_available', '__return_true');
```